# MySQL table autoincremeted column

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

I've created mini-cms. Every page has unique id. Users can add, edit, delete pages.

Lets say we have 10 pages, and user1 deletes his pages 5-8. So now we have pages with id's 1,2,3,4,9,10. Is it possible to fill rows with id's 5-8 next time? If yes how to search for them and fill? BTW, my 'id' field is autoincremented

Comment: i don't think it is a good idea because a visitor that went to yoursite.com/page/5 one day will get another page later if the user had deleted page 5 and create a new one (over).

Comment: no..With autoincremented id cant do it. :(

Comment: maybe. but visitor sees links name, not id of page

Comment: @Chandresh is there any way to do it?

Comment: @TheCoder you should not do it under any circumstances. This is the primary key. It's OK to have missing values. It's not OK however to re-use values. What is your issue with having missing values - most likely you are trying to solve the wrong problem right now

Comment: The problem is i have only 50 pages, but used 200 id's

Comment: @TheCoder Why is that a problem? A database can handle numbers up to 200 just fine.

Comment: @TheCoder you can have 2 billion ids (assuming that the id is int), and even  more with bigint, so you really do not have a problem here.

Comment: lets talk about @Chandresh's idea. My Idea is following: search for this id's with php function within pages table, if there is any missing id then get all empty tables in array, then assign lowest one. else put autoincremented value. But i can't figure out how to search for them

Comment: Voted to close as the OP refuse to listen and insists on his lame feature with not a slightest reason.

Comment: @The Coder - I don't know why you think your "idea" is any good at all. Just don't do it and try to listen to other people. `UNSIGNED INT` can handle 4 billion and a few million records. A number you won't exceed for quite a few decades.

Answer (score 3):

First off, you need a solid reason why you want to achieve the reuse of deleted ID's.
Primary key is there to uniquely identify a record. Period. It's not for people's personal preferences of display or what not, it's there for an actual, solid, logical reason - hence it's called the **primary key**.

Quite frankly, what's the point? Whether the `id` is 1 or 201321941 makes 0 difference to the computer. If it you think it's "ugly" for having gaps after you delete something, then you need to change your logic and stop using auto_increments, or at least conform to them.

First thing you need to know is that you **never**, ever want to tamper with `auto_increment`.
Why?

First off, `auto_increment` is always used for primary key with MySQL tables, and therefore it's a surrogate primary key which means MySQL determines how to generate it physically. If you add human factor to an algorithm that deals with sensitive stuff (such as always, correctly generate next integer for a specific table, taking transactions and what not into account) - you get a disaster.

Second, for some engines such as InnoDB, primary key determines physical storage order of the data. What does that mean? Say you have 1 million entries in your table, and the way the InnoDB stores data is to append the latest record to the data file since every next id is larger than previous. Then, you, say, delete number 500,000 and you want to reuse it. That means that physically, InnoDB has to insert the record at the line 500,000 (simplified explanation) and reorder the b-tree to conform to the change which is much more expensive than just to append data.

There are also other reasons that I really don't want to mention now, but if you want some sort of sequential order or display of your identifiers - then create another field called sequence_id or something similar and create a trigger that will properly handle it (increment it or decrement it).
Otherwise, don't do something that might hurt you.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't do that.

Unique identifier **is not a number.**  It is unique identifier. Unique one. Understand?
One should never ever touch an unique identifier. It identifies the row and should be stuck with it forever.

As to your "problem",

1. I doubt anyone will ever notice such inconsistence in numbers. Especially if you have some hierarchy for your pages.
2. If you want nice urls for your site - make them real nice, with slugs reading `news`, `articles` etc. It would be much better than your silly ordered numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if ID is not an Auto-incremented. 
And at the time of deleting records (pages) you should store all the IDs in one another table and create the log of deleted records. now when you insert any new records at that time you can check the deleted records id with the current records table; if that id not exist over there then you can create that id by query.. 
So by the end of some records your missing record IDs will fill with current records.

The only option in my mind which can take you out of this issues..you can use this option if needed.

Thanks.

Comment: My Idea is following: search for this id's with php function within pages table, get all empty tables in array, then assign lowest one. But i can't figure out how to search for them

Comment: you should get all the ids from the real record table in one array() and also take from deleted record table in second array(), then just check with in_array() function in php. i.e: if(!in_array($arr1['id'],$arr2['id'])){ insert query with deleted ids; }else{ insert with regular ids; } i think this will work. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can do (you have to remove auto-increment) :

```
SELECT id FROM page_table ORDER BY id ASC
```

Then you find the first id number that is not set

```
// $result is a one dimension array containing all ids (so you have to parse what sql query returns before)

$autoIncStartVal = 1;

$nextId = null;

// count($result) + 1 if there is no "hole" in id (so $nextId will be count($result) + 1
for($i=0;$i<count($result) + 1;$i++) { 

  if(!isset($result[$i]) OR $result[$i] != $i + $autoIncStartVal) {
    $nextId = $i+$autoIncStartVal;
    break;
  }

}
```

**Example :**

```
$result = array(1,2,4,5);

$autoIncStartVal = 1;
$nextId = null;

    for($i=0;$i<count($result) + 1;$i++) { 
      if(!isset($result[$i]) OR $result[$i] != $i + $autoIncStartVal) {
        $nextId = $i+$autoIncStartVal;
        break;
      }
    }

var_dump($nextId); // 3
```

**This will find the next id at the precise moment of the execution of the SQL request. 
If two requests are executed at the same time, They will returns the same id and therefore, $nextid will have the same value 2 times**

Comment: And what happens if 2 requests execute at the same time? What guarantees atomicity in your code?

Comment: You are right, i just tried to find a solution to get the next id, but in that case collisions require attention.